# Less reserved memory (default pool) in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Firstly I found that every time SQL agent job failure occurred because there was less reserved memory (default pool) and hence a requesting query was forced to wait in resource semaphore queue.

Luckily I found the log for a failure only where it can been seen that requesting query was in queue and waiting for memory. Within few milliseconds the requesting query was got timed-out due to memory not granted and that caused over all job failure.

I am looking for solution.

Comment: This is very generic. You need to analyze your queries, get execution plans for them and investigate what kind of issues there are with memory grants (if any). There's no magic knob you can turn that will somehow fix this (not even installing more memory, necessarily, as some queries can have grants computed that exceed all reasonable bounds).

Comment: Exceptionally this issue is occurring. I checked the query plan which is perfect. I beleive that issue occurs due to multiple memory request at a same time. Do we can trace this one?

Comment: You may not be looking at the query causing the issues, but just the one that has to wait. If you have at least SP3, there are some [improvements to extended events](https://support.microsoft.com/help/3107173/) that give more insight in memory grants.